# understanding roll method in calendar class

Tags: java, date, calendar

If today's date is 19 July 2014
then my code works as follows :

`Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();`

My code and output is:

`c.roll(3, true);
System.out.print(c.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));`
o/p : 26 6 2014

`c.roll(2, true);
System.out.print(c.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR))` o/p : 19 7 2014

`c.roll(1, true);
System.out.print(c.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR))` o/p : 19 6 2015

roll now will add 1st parameter to my date and give the answer. Am i write? once it is adding to year once to the month... I am not getting the exact working of this method. Please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See javadoc of [roll()-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#roll-int-boolean-). You should really use the predefined Calendar-constants for readability and avoiding errors. So your integer constants has following meaning:

`c.roll(1, true);` // is effectively the same as `c.roll(YEAR, true);`

`c.roll(2, true);` // is effectively the same as `c.roll(MONTH, true);`

`c.roll(3, true);` // is effectively the same as `c.roll(WEEK_OF_YEAR, true);`

**Important:** Be aware of the fact that rolling is different from adding a temporal amount. If you roll up the month December then you will just change to January in CURRENT year, not in next year! So I bet you are rather interested in the method [add(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add-int-int-) using 1 as second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Use the field constants within `Calendar` rather than passing integer constants. Then the method calls make a bit more sense:

```
c.roll(Calendar.MONTH, true);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#YEAR
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY